# How come `0F 1A /r` and `0F 1B /r` have been NOP before Intel MPX?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

On processors which don't support Intel MPX the documentation says that all MPX instructions are NOP. Namely, as I've looked through all these instructions, they all appear to be `0F 1A /r` or `0F 1B /r` unprefixed or prefixed with `F3`, `F2` or `66` bytes, depending on the instruction. Also, there are statements like for `BNDMK`:

> The reg-reg form of this instruction retains legacy behavior (NOP).

I've tried to search these opcodes in [PDF](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/0d/53/319433-022.pdf) (namely my search string was `0F 1`), but all I found there was only description of MPX instructions. Looking in Instruction Set Reference from February 2014, I've found lots of instructions of this form, but they were not NOPs, e.g. `F2 0F 12 /r` is `MOVDDUP`. And looking specifically for `0F 1A` and `0F 1B` I failed to find anything there.

Looking for NOP I found multibyte NOP `0F 1F /0`, but it doesn't coincide with MPX instructions form.

So my question is, where is it documented that the legacy behavior of `0F 1A /r` and `0F 1B /r` is NOP? Is it some general rule for this form of instructions, or maybe they represent some non-NOP instruction in NOP form (like `90` standing for `xchg eax,eax`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intel pdfs I have lying around indeed don't list those as `NOP` either, the block `0F 19-1E` are empty in the opcode table *A-3. Two-byte Opcode Map: 08H -- 7FH (First Byte is 0FH)*. A footnote says *All blanks in all opcode maps are reserved and must not be used. Do not depend on the operation of undefined or reserved locations.*

I also have AMD pdf *24594--Rev. 3.19--September 2012*, and that does list the aforementioned block as being `NOP` in the opcode table *A-4. Secondary Opcode Map (Two-byte Opcodes), Low Nibble 8­-Fh*. However, the page for the actual `NOP` instruction only lists `0F 1F`.

Comment: So I conclude that it was an undocumented for general public feature, consistently implemented by Intel and AMD until MPX, and AMD just released the documentation for it. Got it, thanks!